# How to efficiently create a vertex with a label and several properties?

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

I want to create a vertex with a given label and some properties. Since the `g.addVertexWithLabel()` method only takes the label as an argument and I cannot find any `v.addLabel()` method, it seems that I have to add the properties one by one after creating the vertex.

Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  As of Titan 0.5.4, there is no API that allows you to add it all at once.  In fact, even the Gremlin Groovy sugar of:

```
g.addVertex([name:"stephen"])
```

just calls `Element.setProperty(k,v)` for each key/value pair in the `Map`.  In TinkerPop3 and Titan 0.9/1.0, you can do:

```
g.addVertex(T.label,"person","name","stephen")
```

so it is a bit nicer assuming you are using the newer version.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was hoping for. Do you have an estimate on when a stable version of Titan 0.9 will be released?

Comment: Titan 0.9.0-M2 just [released last night](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aureliusgraphs/mT7Cac9FOuE).  Technically, there won't be a 0.9 stable.  It will go right to Titan 1.0 when TP3 GA release in a few weeks.