# Create a vertex with Label in Gremlin

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

This seems like a must have feature for graph query language, but I cannot find a command that let me create a vertex with label, nor add a label after a vertex has been created.

I tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727307/how-to-efficiently-create-a-vertex-with-a-label-and-several-properties), but it does not work because the property `T.label` is not recognized.

I am using OrientDB as the db engine, and OrientDB has class hierarchy concept rather than Label concept, and I wonder if that is the problem.

Comment: `T.label` is only supported starting from gremlin 3, afaik. What gremlin version do you use?

Comment: It comes with OrientDB 2. I suppose it is 2.6.

Comment: I guess you could simply add a property with key `label` to each vertex. You should still be able to query vertices by the property 'label' efficiently given the label is indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed it in the tutorial [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Tutorial-Java.html)

You can use `g.addVertex("class:className")`